# computing fft of damped waves

Tags: matlab, fft, physics

I have a time series which is a linear combination of damped waves. The data is real.

Y(t) =SUM_w exp(- gamma t) sin(omega t)

There is no analytic form but this is a closest guess. I want to fourier analyze (FFT) such data and get the real frequencies and damping rates.

I am using matlab but any tool would be fine
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question would be a better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com, where LaTeX rendering is available for formula. Instead, you have to use e.g. this bookmarklet for proper display:

```
javascript:(function(){function%20a(a){var%20b=a.createElement('script'),c;b.src='https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js',b.type='text/javascript',c='MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax:{inlineMath:[[\'$\',\'$\']],displayMath:[[\'\\\\[\',\'\\\\]\']],processEscapes:true}});MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();',window.opera?b.innerHTML=c:b.text=c,a.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b)}function%20b(b){b.MathJax===undefined?a(b.document):b.MathJax.Hub.Queue(new%20b.Array('Typeset',b.MathJax.Hub))}var%20c=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),d,e;b(window);for(d=0;d<c.length;d++)e=c[d].contentWindow||c[d].contentDocument,e.document||(e=e.parentNode),b(e)})()
```

First of all, I assume your function is more precisely of the kind
$\sum\limits_k e^{-\gamma_k t}\sin(\omega_k t)$ for $t>0$ and $0$ for $t<0$ (otherwise the function would tend to infinity for $t\to-\infty$). Since a damped function is not periodic, you cannot use Fourier analysis but have to use the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), which yields an amplitude for *continuous* frequencies instead of discrete ones. Using the complex representation $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, each term in the sum can be Fourier transformed individually, yielding

$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-\gamma_k t}\sin(\omega_k t)e^{-i\omega t}\,dt = \frac{\omega_k}{2\pi[(\gamma+i\omega)^2+\omega_k^2]} = \frac{\omega_k}{2\pi}\frac{(\gamma^2-\omega^2+\omega_k^2) + 2i\gamma\omega\omega_k}{[\gamma^2-\omega^2+\omega_k^2]^2+4\gamma^2\omega^2}$

Since you state the damped sine is only a guess, you have to discretize this unlimited integral somehow, though due to the damping a cutoff at some sufficiently large time $t$ should be in order. *If* the damping $\gamma_k$ is actually the same for all summands, your life becomes easier: Multiply the data by $e^{+\gamma t}$ to obtain a periodic signal which you can now really FFT on.

Answer (score 0):

First digitize your function:

```
t=0:dt:T; % define sampling interval dt and duration T according to your needs
Y=sum(exp(-gamma*t).*sin(omega*t));
```

Then do fft and plot:

```
Y_f=fft(Y);
plot(abs(Y_f));
```